# 2-pullbacks in 2-functor 2-categories

Tags: limits-colimits, pullback, 2-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be 2-categories, and let $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]$ be the 2-category of 2-functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. If $\mathcal{D}$ has 2-pullbacks, does it follow that $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]$ also has 2-pullbacks, which can be formed ''pointwise'' in some sense? And is there some reference in the literature that discusses the formation of 2-pullbacks (and more general 2-limits) in 2-functor 2-categories?

Comment: No real answer, but why shouldn't the easy argument from 1-categories directly take over? Also, can you please specify what a 2-limit and 2-functor is for you? There are several types and it seems that no type has become the universal standard (weak, strong, lax, strict, ...).

Comment: In case everything is strict, you just have a Cat-enriched version of the 1-categorical statement, so that's easy and probably covered in Kelly's book on enriched categories.

Comment: Yes, it is likely that the argument from 1-categories should apply in this context. By "2-functor" I mean a strict 2-functor (between strict 2-categories), and by "2-pullback" I mean the notion described on the nLab here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-pullback.